# How to determine the current or latest version of WhatsApp Desktop (for macOS or Windows) available for download?

Tags: windows, macos, download, version, whatsapp

How can one determine the current or latest version of WhatsApp Desktop (for macOS or Windows) available for download?

The current obstacles:

1. It appears one can not determine [the downloadable version](https://www.whatsapp.com/download) from https://www.whatsapp.com until it's installed.
2. I see no place to "check for upgrades" in the macOS desktop app.
3. Currently, the App Store install (Version 0.3.9309) is an older than [the downloadable version](https://www.whatsapp.com/download) from https://www.whatsapp.com, so auto-upgrades from App Store do not appear to be useful.

I do not have a Windows machine, so I have not been able to test anything there. But I ask for Windows version-detection as well, for the sake of my current and future team members (no current team members with Windows).

Comment: Where did you install it from initially? App Store or direct, the versioning may be different. one will not be an update of the other, directly. There is likely to be functionality in the direct version that Apple will not allow in the App Store, hence the disparity.

Comment: They only seem to advertise the [beta updates](https://wabetainfo.com/) :/

Comment: @Tetsujin - I initially installed from https://www.whatsapp.com/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS, in a browser, go to https://web.whatsapp.com/desktop/mac/releases.

You will get something that looks something like this:

```
{"name":"2.2210.9","notes":"2.2210.9","url":"https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.16592-6/10000000_3179600072286747_8209932109665859618_n.zip/release-2.2210.9.zip?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=ab91e1&_nc_ohc=kvDpPN1QqEsAX-orkrR&_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&oh=00_AT-KOFvfJld4KcnshBbvXRqnUbTp8vEMteGgTp5OBAwYHA&oe=6251BC69","pub_date":"2022-03-24T13:52:01-07:00"}
```

The "name" field is your latest release version.

---

****EDIT** After reviewing the Homebrew cask package, it seems that the version returned by `brew info --cask whatsapp` has to be manually updated via a git pull request after a whatsapp update is released. The below method may not be correct just after a whatsapp update. The browser method above will always return the latest version however.**

Alternatively, with [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed, run the following in Terminal:

```
brew update
brew info --cask whatsapp
```

The output should look something like this:

```
% brew update
Already up-to-date.
% brew info --cask whatsapp
whatsapp: 2.2208.14 (auto_updates)
https://www.whatsapp.com/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/whatsapp.rb
==> Name
WhatsApp
==> Description
Desktop client for WhatsApp
==> Artifacts
WhatsApp.app (App)
```

Comment: Hooray for (home)brew!  I love it, thanks @Cancun101.

Comment: The version printout at the weblink (https://web.whatsapp.com/desktop/mac/releases?platform=darwin&arch=x64) is also super helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Downvoter(s): please explain why you downvoted. For me (the question asker), this answer nails it. (Yet another example of how StackExchange loves to frown upon useful information.)

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out what the version link for the Windows version is? Also, how did you find the macOS link originally?

Comment: @XJDHDR No, unfortunately. I tried all variations of replacing "mac" with "windows" in that URL I could think of; everything I tried 2 years ago as well as today just redirected to https://web.whatsapp.com/. Curiously, however, the extra parameters in the mac URL after the question mark appear to do nothing. I can change or just omit those and I always get the same output, assuming the rest of the URL doesn't change.

Comment: @XJDHDR As for how I found that URL in the first place, I believe I pulled it from the Homebrew cask definition file itself. You can see that on github here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/whatsapp.rb. Unfortunately Homebrew is a Mac-specific package manager, so there's no direct mention of a Windows link there. As for how that link was originally found, I have no idea. The commit history of that file is your best bet for a place to start digging though.

Comment: @next-door-tech
Perhaps the Mac version uses a special way of checking for updates using that URL, which isn't present on the Windows version. 

I tried emailing WhatsApp for help about this. Unsurprisingly, they were not helpful but worth a shot (first tried to give me tutorials for updating WhatsApp, then tutorials for using WhatsApp on PC, then hypocritically accused me of ignoring their replies).

Comment: @johnny-utahh - That said, I think I found an equivalent answer for the Windows portion of the question. After the email fails, I used Fiddler to do some packet sniffing and found the following URL: https://web.whatsapp.com/check-update?version=1&platform=win32  It appears to give some info comparing the queried WhatsApp version (the "version=" parameter) with the latest version. One of those pieces of info being the latest version's version number ("currentVersion":"<number>").

Comment: @XJDHDR Awesome find! I played around with the query parameters on that link a bit. Looks like `platform=` can be set to one of `win32` `win64` or `darwin` - all three returned the same `"currentVersion":"2.2210.9"` but I assume it would be different if one platform falls behind a few releases. Interestingly, `version=` only creates an error if it is left unset. I still get a valid response when I set it to something nonsensical, like `version=asdf`.

Comment: I wonder if we can find a way to get the current *beta* version with that link? I tried appending `&beta=true`, `&beta=yes`, and `&beta=1` but the response didn't change. Additionally, I tried `?version=2.2212.1&platform=darwin` (2.2212.1 is the current mac beta build) but I still got `"beta":false` in the response. I can't spend more time investigating right now but I'll try packet sniffing the macOS beta application to see if I can find something once I'm home this evening.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the app but do not install, do a properties on the (details tab) on the exe file as I did, for Windows 64bit, currently it is 0.4.315, probably can do this for the mac version using a mac PC.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeking how to determine the version that's running on my OS/system/machine. I'm looking to determine the latest-released version available from WhatsApp the company.

Comment: You did not read, I never said to install it. The latest is the one they offer at the time, I showed you how to find the version number after you download but DO NOT INSTALL it.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad for my misread. I still want something provides version info without having to download software (eg: reading version on the web page) and/or upgrade to the latest version of an installed app (see homebrew for macOS) when requested. If I understand correctly, this answer suggests I download a file/package/software just to peer at it's properties (through an rather-technical process) just to get the version number of what I downloaded. While _technically_ answer, this does not server the intent or spirit of the question. Regardless - thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Evidently there is no solution but mine for Windows.

Comment: maybe there's a "windows" platform weblink like this one for mac (as mentioned by Cancun101 in the mac-based answer here)?  https://web.whatsapp.com/desktop/mac/releases?platform=darwin&arch=x64

Comment: Regarding a link for the windows version, all the URLs I checked before posting 302 redirected to web.whatsapp.com/ - I can do more digging however.